# How to sort array containing key value pair according to date

Tags: javascript, angular

Below is array. 
What I have to do is sort array according to latest date.
So basically if you look the code after sorting id:12 should come before id:23

I have tried

```
   myArray.sort(function(a, b) {
   return a.date- b.date;
   });
```

but it is not working

```
0:    
{ id: 23
name: "joe"
price: 2300
date: "2018-06-01T09:48:18.000Z"},
1:
{ id: 12
name: "ali"
price: 300
date: "2018-09-01T09:48:1i.000Z"},
```

Comment: why sort by `time` effects `id`?

Answer (score 2):

the following example explains how to sort the array by dates

```js
    var array=[{'date':'2018-06-05T09:48:18.000Z'},{'date':'2018-06-01T09:48:18.000Z'},{'date':'2018-04-01T09:48:18.000Z'}];
    array.sort(function(a,b){
      //convert your string into dates
      return new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date);
    });
    console.log(array)
```

Comment: giving error The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.

Comment: array.sort(function(a,b){
              return new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date);
            });

Comment: I have used    ` array = Object.values(obj);`

Comment: change your array to the following and try again

`var array=[{'date':'2018-06-05T09:48:18.000Z'},{'date':'2018-06-01T09:48:18.000Z'},{'date':'2018-04-01T09:48:18.000Z'}];`

Comment: I am using your code but  return new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date); is giving error of "the left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type"

Answer (score 1):

By using an [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) compliant date, you could take the strings directly for sorting with [`String#localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare).

```js
var array =  [{ id: 23, name: "joe", price: 2300, date: "2018-06-01T09:48:18.000Z" }, { id: 12, name: "ali", price: 300, date: "2018-09-01T09:48:1i.000Z" }];

array.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b.date.localeCompare(a.date); // desc
});

console.log(array);
```

Comment: It is partially sorting data according to date.